# Microsoft Sql Server Database data to google firebase

Tags: sql-server, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, integration

Is it possible to send my sql server database data via stored procedures, to my google firebase database? How can I do that? I am new to use firebase, please show me a way to do that.

Comment: You have two options: 1) MSXML or 2) SQL CLR.  There is plenty of information on Google about both.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick, i wiil searching about them :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Can you also outline what the purpose is? Why do you want to do that and what is the expected result since the SQL data is handled in an entirely different fashion than the NoSQL data.

Comment: Same question here. To answer the question from Jay, here is the purpose: we have an enterprise server behind a firewall and would like to extract specific data to send to firebase on other to make a Backend for a mobile application. Using a stored procedure seems like a potential simple and secure solution.